# Python and Sqlite3, concatenate passed strings

Tags: python, sqlite

The following is a generalisation of my problem

```
Col_Index = 'Foo'
data = SQLfunctions.fetchSQL("SELECT Col_" + Col_Index + "FROM MyTable)
```

Where `fetchSQL` is a function that returns the values of the SQL statement. I tried to re-write this so as to pass the `Col_Index` using `?` and concatenate the strings i.e.

```
data = SQLfunctions.fetchSQL("SELECT Col_ || ? FROM MyTable", [Col_Index])
```

But this did not work as it did not seem to perform the `||` with the `?` (error something like `column Col_ does not exist`).

How do I change this to make it work?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use SQL parameters for anything other than values.

You cannot use them for table names or columns or SQL functions or any other part of the SQL grammar, *precisely* because they are designed to prevent such use.

In other words, if SQL parameters could be used to produce SQL code (including object names), they would be useless for one of their main uses: to prevent SQL injection attacks.

You are stuck with generating that part of your query, I am afraid.

Do be *very, very* careful with user-provided data, don't ever take `Col_Index` from external sources without sanitizing and/or severely restricting the range of values it can hold.

You could look at [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) to generate the SQL for you, as it ensures that any object names are properly escaped as well:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import table, literal_column, select

tbl = table('MyTable')
column = literal_column('Col_' + Col_Index)
session.execute(select([column], '', [tbl]))
```